# HamlBars attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, ember.js, handlebars.js

Hello there I'm using hamlbars and have some troubles with attrs assignment.

```
%div{class => "result_#{hb 'item.id'}"}
```

and it compiles as

```
<div class=\'result_{{item.id}}\'></div>
```

Is there any way to assign attributes easily because of 'bind' method looks ugly especially when you trying to assign data attributes?

Comment: What do you want it to look like in the end?

Answer (score 1):

For me this code did not work because of a missing colon:

`%div{:class => "result_#{hb 'item.id'}"}`

Not sure if this will solve your specific problem but just in case other users see this and ran into the same issue I did of not compiling at all.